# Prove by contradiction using division algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $z$ be a primitive $n$-th root of unity. Prove that for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, if $z^k=1$, then $n \mid k$.

Comment: Your proof as it stands does not mean anything. You should say: Suppose $n \nmid k$. Then by the division algorithm we can write $k = nm + l$ where $0 < l < n$. Then $z^l = 1$ contradicting $n$ being the ***smallest positive integer*** such that $z^n = 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We start a proof by contradiction by accepting the premise:

> Let $z$ be a primitive n-th root of unity. For $k\in \mathbb Z$, suppose $z^k = 1$.

Then we suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that the desired conclusion is false:

> Suppose $n \not \mid k$.

Then we see where those givens and the supposition take us:

By the division algorithm we can express $k$ as such: there exists a unique integer $m$ and $r$ such that $k = nm + r$, where $0 \lt r \lt n$. Then prove that this leads to the fact that $$z^k = 1 \iff = z^{nm+ r} = 1 \iff z^{nm}z^r =1 \iff z^r = 1$$ which contradicts the fact that $n$ must be the smallest positive integer such that $z^n=1$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\rm\ \ z^K = 1 = z^N\:\Rightarrow\: z^{\,K\ mod\ N} = 1\ \ [\ \cdots\, \Rightarrow\: Z^{gcd(K,N)} = 1]$

**Remark** $\ $ More generally, any nonempty set $\rm\:S\ne \{0\}\:$ of integers closed under subtraction has the form $\rm\: d\,\Bbb Z,\:$ where $\rm\:d\:$ is the least positive element or, equivalently, $\rm\:d = gcd(S).\:$ In the above case where $\rm\:S = \{n\in\Bbb Z\,:\, z^n = 1\},\:$ we call $\rm\:d\:$ the *order* of $\rm\:z.$ The inductive proof is essentially the Euclidean algorithm, i.e. $\rm\:S\:$ closed under remainder (mod) $\rm\:\Rightarrow\:S\:$ closed under gcd. In fact it suffices for $\rm\:S\:$ to be closed under subtraction, since the remainders arise by iterated subtraction (the Division Algorithm). This essence of the matetr will be clarified when one learns about *ideals*, e.g [order ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+order+ideal) (e.g. as above), and [denominator ideals.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+denominator+ideal)